# Is this dangerous to my Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku, newrelic

We are hosted on Heroku, and have the NewRelic add on. Every day I check the errors, and almost every day this error comes up.

**Action and Type**

```
Middleware/Rack/Rack::MethodOverride#call
EOFError
```

**Message**

```
bad content body
```

This is a Rails Application, and so I figure it's not doing anything in particular other than returning a 440 response status because there is nothing at the url they are trying to access.

**URL**

```
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Through some google-fu I found an article pertaining to this being a brute force attack on wordpress sites.

My specific question is:

*Do I worry about this?*

I inherited the site and am not sure if this is just something that happens, and if it is something that rails applications don't have to worry about? It seems fairly targeted towards wordpress, but I can't find any documentation on whether I should be doing more to stop this.

**Other frequently pinged urls that don't exist on my application**

```
/sites/all/libraries/elfinder/php/connector.minimal.php

/license.php

/tiny_mce/plugins/tinybrowser/upload_file.php
```

Any enlightenment on the subject would be great. Stack trace available if needed. Thanks in advance, overflowers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't have a route configured to handle those requests you then only have to worry about getting spammed these requests and losing network resources.  They'll recieve a 404 Not Found error when they try to reach it and so there is nothing they can really do except slow your site if they spam requests.  If they do it often you can ban their IP address.

Comment: It's like five similar requests every 2-3 days. If it's not malicious, I won't worry.